# PHP in_array returns false positive

Tags: php, arrays

I'm checking whether a checkbox should be checked against a user preferences array of id's with:

```
if(in_array($category['id'], $checkedarray)){
  $checked = "checked='checked'";
}
```

the result of checked array looks something like:

```
array(43) {
[0]=>
string(2) "31"
[1]=>
string(2) "32"
[2]=>
string(2) "34"
[3]=>
string(2) "35"
}
```

In the above array example, 33 still returns true even though its not in there.

I've tried using:

```
(in_array($category['id'],$checkedarray, true)
```

The results were same as without the strict condition.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u upload it to code pad, the exact test case

Comment: The if block is missing a ) before the opening {. I'm guessing that was just an error in translation?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, i retyped here instead of copy/paste.  I'll change it in a sec, but it does have proper brackets, else it'd returns errors.

Comment: This works fine as shown.  Can you show us the *exact* case that caused the problem?  I ran your code at a site called [Ideone](http://ideone.com), you can upload an example there, too.  http://ideone.com/FaMiw

Comment: Ok, just a silly double check since I can't see a possible else resetting $checked, you don't happen to be declaring $checked outside the loop and forgetting to reset it the next time around the loop?

Comment: Rocket, unfortunately for me, that pretty much IS the exact code, just the shortened version of the array since it has about 100 values in it.

Comment: @Joachim, good point, i'll double check that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

33 does NOT return true -- you're simply never resetting your `$checked` variable.

```
if (true) { $checked = "checked" };
if (false) { /* never gets executed */ }
```

add an else!

```
if (in_array(33, $checkedarray)) {
    $checked = "checked='checked'";
} else {
    $checked = "";
}
```

Comment: I feel like a tool,  made the assumption that a blank else condition pretty much did that.

Comment: I had an else, but it was blank, as in }else{ //}

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. The only reason I know this is because I've been there :)